# Difference Between Two Date Columns In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This returns no errors in PHP, but instead of doing the math calculation, it simply returns blank for the final column (all other columns work fine).

```
SELECT 
    mantis_category_table.name, 
    mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y") AS DATE2, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified), "%m-%d-%Y") AS FirstOfdate_modified,
    TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified), "%m-%d-%Y")) - TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y"))
```

How can I properly get the difference between the 3rd and 4th items (both dates) in my select statement.

I have already tried DATEDIFF like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE2,FirstOfdate_modified)
```

And it doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have 2 unix timestamps.

The FROM_UNIXTIME() formats them to a string, and subtracting strings isn't a valid operation.
(The to_day maybe makes it worse...)

But why don't you subtract the unix timestamps? You will get the result in seconds, but it should work fine.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    mantis_category_table.name, 
    mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y") AS DATE2, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified), "%m-%d-%Y") AS FirstOfdate_modified,
    (min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified)- mantis_bug_table.date_submitted)/ 86400 as day_difference.
```